# Using MySQL, Is it necessary to mention the columns in same order as in the index?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table artists which has an index like this

```
combo1 => by_id, origin, genre
```

I run the queries

```
SELECT * FROM artists 
    WHERE by_id = '324' 
      AND genre = 'rock' 
      AND origin = 'Australia'
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM artists 
    WHERE by_id = '324' 
      AND origin = 'Australia' 
      AND genre = 'rock'
```

Clearly, in the second query the columns are mentioned as they are in the index. When I run `EXPLAIN` on these, it says it *is* using the index. But I am a bit confused whether the second one would be faster then the first one. Is it?

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference as the optimizer would take care of the order as long as the columns are included.

```
WHERE by_id = '324' AND origin = 'Australia' AND genre = 'rock'
```

```
| ID | SELECT_TYPE |   TABLE |  TYPE | POSSIBLE_KEYS |     KEY | KEY_LEN |               REF | ROWS |       EXTRA |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |      SIMPLE | artists | const |       PRIMARY | PRIMARY |      80 | const,const,const |    1 | Using index |
```

```
WHERE by_id = '324' AND genre = 'rock' AND origin = 'Australia'
```

```
| ID | SELECT_TYPE |   TABLE |  TYPE | POSSIBLE_KEYS |     KEY | KEY_LEN |               REF | ROWS |       EXTRA |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |      SIMPLE | artists | const |       PRIMARY | PRIMARY |      80 | const,const,const |    1 | Using index |
```

If you had happened to leave out `by_id`, the index would have not been used (indexes work left to right)

```
WHERE genre = 'rock'
```

```
| ID | SELECT_TYPE |   TABLE |  TYPE | POSSIBLE_KEYS |     KEY | KEY_LEN |    REF | ROWS |                    EXTRA |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |      SIMPLE | artists | index |        (null) | PRIMARY |      80 | (null) |    1 | Using where; Using index |
```

```
WHERE origin='Australia' AND genre = 'rock'
```

```
| ID | SELECT_TYPE |   TABLE |  TYPE | POSSIBLE_KEYS |     KEY | KEY_LEN |    REF | ROWS |                    EXTRA |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |      SIMPLE | artists | index |        (null) | PRIMARY |      80 | (null) |    1 | Using where; Using index |
```

Answer (score -3):

Second query should be more faster than first.

The order in which columns are listed in the index definition is important. It is possible to retrieve a set of row identifiers using only the first indexed column. However, it is not possible or efficient (on most databases) to retrieve the set of row identifiers using only the second or greater indexed column.

For example, imagine a phone book that is organized by city first, then by last name, and then by first name. If you are given the city, you can easily extract the list of all phone numbers for that city. However, in this phone book it would be very tedious to find all the phone numbers for a given last name. You would have to look within each city's section for the entries with that last name. Some databases can do this, others just won’t use the index.

Comment: that is not true. It is important to have the correct columns in the where predicate. but the order the columns are typed in does not matter.

Comment: @javadba: you're both right. Sharad is talking about the order in the index definition, whereas the OP is talking about the order in the WHERE clause. The latter doesn't matter, but the former does. So although Sharad is correct, their answer is not really the answer to this question.

Comment: @javadba: its true order matter in query, you should first check the definition of index.

Comment: @sharad, i just proved the point using explain: i put the first column of the index after the second column of the index and the explain showed it used the index anyways.  I can not repeat it in a comment, takes too much space. Take a look at the accepted answer as well

Comment: @javadba: Okay  but what about this reference http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index, is it wrong?